# HPHP HipHop for PHP make fails at 98%

Tags: php, ubuntu, hiphop

```
[ 98%] Generating systemlib.php
[ 98%] Built target systemlib
Linking CXX executable hhvm
../third_party/thrift/libhphp_thrift.a(TEventBase.cpp.o): In function `apache::thrift::async::TEventBase::SmoothLoopTime::setTimeInterval(unsigned long)':
TEventBase.cpp:(.text+0xf1b): undefined reference to `FLAG__namespace_do_not_use_directly_use_DECLARE_int32_instead::FLAGS_v'
../third_party/thrift/libhphp_thrift.a(TEventBase.cpp.o): In function `apache::thrift::async::TEventBase::SmoothLoopTime::addSample(long, long)':
TEventBase.cpp:(.text+0x119b): undefined reference to `FLAG__namespace_do_not_use_directly_use_DECLARE_int32_instead::FLAGS_v'
../third_party/thrift/libhphp_thrift.a(TEventBase.cpp.o): In function `apache::thrift::async::TEventBase::nothingHandledYet()':
TEventBase.cpp:(.text+0x12a3): undefined reference to `FLAG__namespace_do_not_use_directly_use_DECLARE_int32_instead::FLAGS_v'
../third_party/thrift/libhphp_thrift.a(TEventBase.cpp.o): In function `apache::thrift::async::TEventBase::bumpHandlingTime()':
TEventBase.cpp:(.text+0x14bb): undefined reference to `FLAG__namespace_do_not_use_directly_use_DECLARE_int32_instead::FLAGS_v'
TEventBase.cpp:(.text+0x14e1): undefined reference to `FLAG__namespace_do_not_use_directly_use_DECLARE_int32_instead::FLAGS_v'
../third_party/thrift/libhphp_thrift.a(TEventBase.cpp.o):TEventBase.cpp:(.text+0x1a4b): more undefined references to `FLAG__namespace_do_not_use_directly_use_DECLARE_int32_instead::FLAGS_v' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [hphp/hhvm/hhvm] Error 1
make[1]: *** [hphp/hhvm/CMakeFiles/hhvm.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is on Ubuntu 13.10

It's on a 64 Bit system.

I'm not able to resolve this issue - has anybody experienced the same issue?

I've followed instructions as posted [here](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-13.10).

Comment: there should be minimum *question* (excluding code) length

Comment: Fix the undefined reference?

Comment: is your computer a 32 bit or 64 bit

Comment: Ah - it's a 64 bit system